# The total number of times User U bought Item T out of the 3 recent months

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aggregate

I have the following dataframe:

```
| order_id | item_id        | user_id  | order_date  |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- | ----------- |
| 383706   | 1              |  A       | 2012-09-11  |
| 354776   | 2              |  A       | 2018-05-19  |
|  33333   | 2              |  A       | 2014-01-19  |
| 383706   | 3              |  B       | 2013-12-10  |
```

and i want to calculate this following variable: total_buy_m5(User U, Item T) is the total number of times User U bought Item T out of the 5 most recent months (between 2019-12-01 and 2019-07-01).
I want this final table:

```
 | user_id        | item_id  | count    |
 | -------------- | -------- | -------- |
 | A              |  1       | 100      |
 | A              |  2       | 1        |
 | A              |  3       | 12       |
 | B              |  1       | 5        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `order_date` is of datetime type, you can do this to filter. If not, you have to convert that column to the datetime type.

`df = df[(df['user_id'] == U) & (df['item_id'] == T) & ((df['order_date'] >= start_date) & (df['order_date'] <= end_date))]`

In order to get your final desired table, you can use a `groupby`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Creating some sample data to illustrate the example

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_id', 'item_id', 'order_date'], data=[['a', 1, datetime(2020, 1, 1)], ['a', 1, datetime(2020, 1, 2)]])

# Filter the DataFrame based on your function arguments

df = df[(df['user_id'] == 'a') &
        (df['item_id'] == 1) &
        ((df['order_date'] >= '2019-02-01') & (df['order_date'] <= '2020-02-02'))]

# Now do a groupby and rename the order_date column to count

df2 = df.groupby(['user_id', 'item_id']).count().reset_index()
df3 = df2.rename(columns={'order_date': 'count'})

print(df3)
```

Comment: Thanks @sudeep , but in fact i want have the final table mentionned in the auestion using aggregate or somthing like that

Comment: Edited the answer to aggregate into the desired table format.